# Return keys whose values are true from a Json Object using java

Tags: json, jackson

From below json object , I want to return(/or add the keys to a Set) whose values are true.

```
  {
    "create": true,
    "read": false,
    "update": true,
    "delete": false
  }
```

I want an output like below

`[ create, update ]` 
Could some one help me with this?

Update :

I was trying as shown below to capture all the values that are true , but I think my Java 8 filter criteria is wrong.

```
Map<String, Object> mapping = new ObjectMapper().readValue(permissionStr, HashMap.class);
mySet = mapping.entrySet().stream().filter(x->x.getValue().equals(Boolean.TRUE)).map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Oh come on, this is **extremely easy** even for beginners. What have you already tried yourself, and, if you have, why isn't it working for you? What is that obscure: filtering the keys, reading the JSON document into a JSON object model, generating the output?

Comment: I was trying to do this 
 Map<String, Object> mapping = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonStr, HashMap.class);

permissionSet = mapping.entrySet().stream().filter(x->x.getValue().equals(Boolean.TRUE)).map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

But my filter criteria is wrong I guess.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your update. However, I'd make some remarks: the map is better to be typed as `Map<String, Boolean` so that Jackson could have precise information for the map values type in order not to deserialize it to anything non-boolean and fail-fast. This would also allow you to filter using a more simple predicate. Like this:

Comment: ```private static final TypeReference<Map<String, Boolean>> stringToBooleanMapTypeRef = new TypeReference<>() {}; ... return objectMapper.<Map<String, Boolean>>readValue(json, stringToBooleanMapTypeRef).entrySet().stream().filter(Map.Entry::getValue).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toSet());```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list; 
String VariableName = JSONObjectName.getString("Create");
if(VariableName.equals("true")){
    list.add(VariableName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set each field to default to false in the Java class and annotate the class with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT). This checks the instance of the class you created with a default instance created with a no args constructor and only sends the values that have changed, in your case any value that is true.

When parsing the JSON output, you can then check which keys are in the object.

Comment: There is no need to create a mapping unless the OP clearly mentions it. It still can be done by either reading the JSON document into a `JsonObject` (since the OP clearly mentions the `gson` tag), or using `JsonReader` (the same for the tag).